# Regexp substr in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, regexp-substr

```
Concerta 18 mg/24 hr oral tablet, extended release
```

Expected Output

```
tablet, extended release
```

Input

```
glipiZIDE 10 mg oral tablet, extended release
```

Expected Output

```
tablet, extended release
```

Input

```
Adderall XR 10 mg oral capsule, extended release
```

Expected Output

```
capsule, extended release
```

I used the below query and getting tables or capsule as output.

```sql
select trim(
         regexp_substr(
           lower('Adderall XR 10 mg oral capsule, extended release' ),
           ' ((caps|tab|powd|syr|aero|liq|susp)[a-z]+|solution|lotion|spray|([^a-z0-9])?extended release )+'
         )
       )
from dual;
```

Comment: Your request is missing the most important part: The explanation. By which rule do you want to extract the string? So far it seems it is the text following 'oral ', but will this always be the case? Examples are good, but only when added to an explanation not to substitute it.

Comment: Please don't link to images when not absolutely necessary. And there is still no explanation in your request. Please state the rules precisely that are needed to determine the result string.

Comment: if the word tablet is there in the string I need "tablet" alone in output and the same for "capsule" also. If string contains "capsule, extended release" or "table, extended release" I need only "tablet, extended release" or ""capsule, extended release"

Comment: That would be something like `case when text like '%tablet, extended release%' then 'tablet, extended release' when text like '%tablet%' then 'tablet' when text like '%capsule, extended release%' then ...`. And in case it's neither tablet nor capsule (e.g. liquid) then the result shall be null?

Answer (score 0):

With as many info you posted (read: no explanation at all), why would you need regular expressions? Simple `substr + instr` returns desired output:

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2    (select 1, 'Concerta 18 mg/24 hr oral tablet, extended release' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'glipiZIDE 10 mg inhalation aerosol'                 from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Adderall XR 10 mg subcutaneous solution'            from dual
  5    )
  6  select id,
  7    substr(col, case when instr(col, 'oral')         > 0 then instr(col, 'oral') + 5
  8                     when instr(col, 'inhalation')   > 0 then instr(col, 'inhalation') + 11
  9                     when instr(col, 'subcutaneous') > 0 then instr(col, 'subcutaneous') + 13
 10                end
 11          ) result
 12  from test;

        ID RESULT
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 tablet, extended release
         2 aerosol
         3 solution

SQL>
```

Comment: Pattern may get change in stage data, so am going for regexp_substr eg1-amoxicillin 500 mg oral tablet desired output-table,eg2-acetaminophen-hydrocodone 325 mg-7.5 mg oral tablet output-table,eg3-Toprol-XL 50 mg oral tablet, extended release output-tablet, extended release

Comment: All those values would still be OK if you apply query I posted. Lines #1 - 5 represent **sample data**, you don't need that. Query you do need begins at line #6.

Comment: I have added sample data as image format for your reference

Comment: Aha; there's something else (besides "oral"). I edited the query; have a look. If another option appears, just add it into the CASE expression.

Comment: There are millions of records with different patterns. I can't use this dude

Comment: I doubt it. There aren't *millions* of ways those drugs can be "applied". You either drink them (so it is "oral"), use "inhalation", get them injected, and ... what else? There's a definite number of ways, so you might need to add a couple of WHEN clauses into the CASE expression. What "millions" are you talking about?

Comment: @Sqllearner: Your problem is not SQL here. Again and again you are giving us examples of how a string might look like and what you would the result string to be then. But what is the *rule* to determine the result string? A rule that works for any string, not only a particular example. If you are not able to describe the task to a human, how then do you think you will be able to tell a machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           LOWER(value),
           -- Leading space
           ' '
           -- Dosage form
           || '((caps|tab|powd|syr|aero|liq|susp)[a-z]*|solution|lotion|spray)'
           -- Optional trailing punctuation then "extended release"
           || '([^a-z0-9]*extended release)?'
         )
       ) AS dosage_form
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'Concerta 18 mg/24 hr oral tablet, extended release' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'glipiZIDE 10 mg oral tablet, extended release'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Adderall XR 10 mg oral capsule, extended release'   FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DOSAGE_FORM |
> | --- |
> | tablet, extended release |
> | tablet, extended release |
> | capsule, extended release |

---

Alternatively, you can list all the dosage forms in a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dosage_forms (form) AS
SELECT 'capsule'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'capslet'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'caps'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tablet'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'powder'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'syringe'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'aerosol'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'liquid'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'suspension' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'solution'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'lotion'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'spray'      FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE dosage_form_modifiers (form_modifier) AS
SELECT 'extended release' FROM DUAL;
```

then use the query (from Oracle 12):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
                  t.value,
                  '( |^)'
                  || '('
                  || form
                  || form_modifier
                  || ')',
                  1,
                  1,
                  'i',
                  2
                ) AS match
         FROM   dosage_forms df
                CROSS JOIN (
                  SELECT '[^a-z0-9]*' || form_modifier AS form_modifier
                  FROM   dosage_form_modifiers
                UNION ALL
                  SELECT NULL FROM DUAL
                ) dfm
         ORDER BY
                LENGTH(match) DESC NULLS LAST,
                match NULLS LAST
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       )
       ON (1 = 1)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9d9c6f2a55744457874c3a2900b48b6f)*